# how i can send CURL request with use proxy in Google App Script

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, curl, google-cloud-platform, proxy

I need send request on API, but for static IP address, I set up my own squid proxy server on the google cloud virtual machine
**what should i write down and how to send analog?**:

```
curl -d "example" -X POST -x http://35.225.50.255:3128 -L https://webhook.site/dcf61fb9-bbb1-452e-9843-7d75b222abed
```

in **Google App Script** my code looks like this and it works, but I can't find anything about proxies in the documentation .,.

```
function doPost(e) {

  if(typeof e !== 'undefined'){
    const req = e.postData.contents;
    makeHTTPrequest(req);
  }


}


function makeHTTPrequest(request){
  
  var d = new Date();
  request = request + d.getTime();

  const secret =  "SECRET_EXAMPLE"; 
  
var byteSignature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(request, secret);
// convert byte array to hex string

var signature = byteSignature.reduce(function(str,chr){
  chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
  return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
},'');

request = request + "&signature=" + signature;

const url = "http://35.225.50.255:3128";
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "X-MBX-APIKEY": "exmplMBIKEY"
        },
        "payload": request
    });

    Logger.log("Response code is %s", response.getResponseCode());
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```